# Symfony 2.6 form validation and error messages

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I am fairly new to Symfony. I have written the below code to validate and return error messaged if validation failed. But I was able to only get the error message not the field which failed the validation. Below is my code:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //do something here
        }

        $errors = $this->get('my_form')->getErrorMessages($form);
        return new JsonResponse(['errors' => $errors], 400);
}
```

Can someone please tell me how can I also get the field name along with the error message.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get all the Errors of a form use `$form->getErrors($deep=true, $flatten=true)` so converting the errors to an array with names as field names and keys as messages will be something like:

```
$errors = $form->getErrors(true, true);
$errorArray = array();
foreach($errors as $e){
  //get the field that caused the error
  $field = $e->getOrigin();
  $errorArray[$field->getName()] = isset($errorArray[$field->getName()]) ? $errorArray[$field->getName()] : array();
  $errorArray[$field->getName()][] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I use:

```
  /**
   * Get errors from form.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form
   * @return array
   */
  private function getErrorsFromForm(FormInterface $form)
  {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
      $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $childForm) {
      if ($childForm instanceof FormInterface) {
        if ($childErrors = $this->getErrorsFromForm($childForm)) {
          $errors[$childForm->getName()] = $childErrors;
        }
      }
    }

    return $errors;
  }
```